# How to detect status HDMI in connected or disconnected for Zidoo Digital Android Box?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, hdmi

I am working with ziddo digital box for HDMI in video play. There are issue while i'm connecting and disconnecting the HDMI. It is freezing the screen.
I am using this code:

```
public class RealtekSurfaceView extends SurfaceView {

public static final String TAG = "RealtekSurfaceView";

//A reference to the context
private Context mContext = null;

//Reference to ViewGroup
private ViewGroup mViewGroup = null;

//Integers to keep the width, height and FPS
private int width = 0;
private int height = 0;
private int fps = 0;

//Reference to the Surface holder
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder = null;
private SurfaceHolder.Callback mSurfaceHolderCallback = null;

//Reference to the Broadcast receiver
private BroadcastReceiver mHdmiRxReceiver = null;

//Boolean to indicate if the HDMI IN is connected
private boolean isConnected = false;

//A few constants to pass the data along
public static final int DISPLAY = 0;
public static final int DISPLAYTIME = 200;

//A reference to a handler
Handler mHandler = null;

//Reference to realtek hdmi manager
private RtkHDMIRxManager mRtkHdmiManager = null;

//Boolean to identify if the display is ON or OFF
public static boolean isPreviewAvailable = false;

//A boolean to denote if we are displaying already
private boolean isDisplayOn = false;

String videoPath;

String videoType;

boolean HDMI_AV=false;




//Constructor to the RealtekSurfaceView class, this will take care of populating the context, view group, surface holder.
//It will also take care of setting up the surfaceholder callback
public RealtekSurfaceView(Context ctx, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    super(ctx);
    this.mContext = ctx;
    this.mViewGroup = viewGroup;
    this.mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
    //Add the callback
    mSurfaceHolderCallback = new SurfaceCallback();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(mSurfaceHolderCallback);
    init();
}

public RealtekSurfaceView(Context context,String filePath,String videoType,int x,int y,int width,int height,boolean HDMI_AV){
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.mContext=context;
    this.videoType=videoType;
    this.width=width;
    this.height=height;
    this.HDMI_AV=HDMI_AV;
    this.videoPath=filePath;
    this.mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
    this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceCallback());
    this.mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}

public void init() {
    //Make the handler instance ready to be used by remaining components
    mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case DISPLAY:
                if (isConnected) {
                    play();
                }
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }
        }
    };
    initHdmiConnect();
}

//Start listening to and processing the incoming HDMI IN connection from the Realtek internal classes
private void initHdmiConnect() {
    mHdmiRxReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            isConnected = intent.getBooleanExtra(HDMIRxStatus.EXTRA_HDMIRX_PLUGGED_STATE, false);
            if (isConnected) {
                play();
            } else {
                stop();
            }
        }
    };
    isConnected = isHdmiConnected(mContext);
    mContext.registerReceiver(mHdmiRxReceiver, new IntentFilter(HDMIRxStatus.ACTION_HDMIRX_PLUGGED));
}

//Function to determine if the HDMI IN is connected
public static boolean isHdmiConnected(Context ctx) {
    Intent batteryStatus = ctx.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(HDMIRxStatus.ACTION_HDMIRX_PLUGGED));
    if(null != batteryStatus) {
        return batteryStatus.getBooleanExtra(HDMIRxStatus.EXTRA_HDMIRX_PLUGGED_STATE, false);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//The surfaceholder.callback implementation, this will try to launch/stop the play by appropriately setting up few variables
private final class SurfaceCallback implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        Log.i("RealtekSurface", "changed");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        isPreviewAvailable = true;
        play();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        isPreviewAvailable = false;
        stop();
    }
}

public boolean play() {
    this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (!isDisplayOn && isPreviewAvailable) {
        mRtkHdmiManager = new RtkHDMIRxManager();
        if (null != mRtkHdmiManager) {
            HDMIRxStatus mHdmiRxStatus = mRtkHdmiManager.getHDMIRxStatus();
            if (mHdmiRxStatus != null && mHdmiRxStatus.status == HDMIRxStatus.STATUS_READY) {
                if (mRtkHdmiManager.open() != 0) {
                    //TODO write code for retrying the same after "t" time using the handler
                    height = 0;
                    width = 0;
                    mRtkHdmiManager = null;
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(DISPLAY, DISPLAYTIME);
                    return false;
                }
                HDMIRxParameters mHdmiRxParams = mRtkHdmiManager.getParameters();
                getSupportedPreviewSizes(mHdmiRxParams, mHdmiRxStatus.width, mHdmiRxStatus.height);
                fps = getSupportedFps(mHdmiRxParams);
            } else {
                if(null!=mHandler)
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(DISPLAY, DISPLAYTIME);
                return false;
            }
            //Following is the code to play
            try {
                mRtkHdmiManager.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
                HDMIRxParameters mParams = new HDMIRxParameters();
                mParams.setPreviewSize(width, height);
                mParams.setPreviewFrameRate(fps);
                mRtkHdmiManager.setParameters(mParams);
                mRtkHdmiManager.play();
                isDisplayOn = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                stop();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else if (!isPreviewAvailable) {
        //TODO write code for retrying the same after "t" time using the handler
        if(null!=mHandler)
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(DISPLAY, DISPLAYTIME);
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void stop() {
    //Reset the visibility of the surface view to invisible, else the HDMI IN will not be able to retrieve this view
    this.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    //Destroy the instance of the running RealTek Manager after stopping that
    if (mRtkHdmiManager != null) {
        mRtkHdmiManager.stop();
        mRtkHdmiManager.release();
        mRtkHdmiManager = null;
    }
    //Reset the booleans to their origin values
    isDisplayOn = false;
    width = 0;
    height = 0;
    fps = 0;
}

private int getSupportedFps(HDMIRxParameters mHdmiRxParameters) {
    List<Integer> previewFrameRates = mHdmiRxParameters.getSupportedPreviewFrameRates();
    int fps = 0;
    if (previewFrameRates != null && previewFrameRates.size() > 0) {
        fps = previewFrameRates.get(previewFrameRates.size() - 1);
    } else {
        fps = 30;
    }
    return fps;
}

private void getSupportedPreviewSizes(HDMIRxParameters mHdmiRxParams, int rxWidth, int rxHeight) {
    List<RtkHDMIRxManager.Size> mPreviewSizes = mHdmiRxParams.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    int retWidth = 0, retHeight = 0;
    if (mPreviewSizes == null || mPreviewSizes.size() <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < mPreviewSizes.size(); i++) {
        if (mPreviewSizes.get(i) != null && rxWidth == mPreviewSizes.get(i).width) {
            retWidth = mPreviewSizes.get(i).width;
            retHeight = mPreviewSizes.get(i).height;
            if (rxHeight == mPreviewSizes.get(i).height) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (retWidth == 0 && retHeight == 0) {
        if (mPreviewSizes.get(mPreviewSizes.size() - 1) != null) {
            width = mPreviewSizes.get(mPreviewSizes.size() - 1).width;
            height = mPreviewSizes.get(mPreviewSizes.size() - 1).height;
        }
    }

    width = retWidth;
    height = retHeight;
}
```

}

While i'm disconnecting and connecting the HDMI it should refresh the screen. There are some issue in the code , it is not able to create the broadcast the disconnect and connect status while running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one issue in your code :

```
public RealtekSurfaceView(Context context,String filePath,String videoType,int x,int y,int width,int height,boolean HDMI_AV){
super(context);
  this.mContext=context;
  this.videoType=videoType;
  this.width=width;
  this.height=height;
  this.HDMI_AV=HDMI_AV;
  this.videoPath=filePath;
  this.mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
  this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceCallback());
  this.mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
  setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

init(); <-- you have to add this, as you are forgetting to initialize the broadcast receiver
```

}